# Android RxJava 2: What is the difference between fromCallable and Just?

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I've been experimenting with RxJava in Android, but I'm trying to figure out the difference between fromCallable and Just. Both receive data just once, versus Create which can receive data multiple times. Here is the code that I'm using to experiment:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listenCallable();
        listenJust();
    }
    private void listenCallable() {
        CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
        Disposable disposable = Shooter.getCallable().subscribe(i -> {
            Log.d("Tag", "Listen Callable: " + i);
        });
        compositeDisposable.add(disposable);
        compositeDisposable.dispose();
    }

    private void listenJust() {
        CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
        Disposable disposable = Shooter.getJust("Jay").subscribe(i -> {
            Log.d("Tag", "Listen Just " + i);
        });
        compositeDisposable.add(disposable);
        compositeDisposable.dispose();
    }
}
```

and the class which is emitting data:

```
public class Shooter {
    public static Observable<String> getCallable() {
        return Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<String>() {
            @Override
            public String call() throws Exception {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (Exception e) {}
                return "Callable Results";
            }
        });
    }

    public static Observable<String> getJust(String input) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        return Observable.just("Just Results " + input);
    }
}
```

Comment: Recommended reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Creating-Observables

Comment: The JavaDocs should be clearly indicate the difference as well: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#just-T-

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Observable.fromCallable(` is analogous to

```
Observable.defer {
    try {
        Observable.just(...)
    } catch(e: Throwable) {
        Observable.error(e)
    }
}
```

Therefore, `just` runs synchronously, while `fromCallable` can be deferred to another `Scheduler` with `subscribeOn` (and executed "later").

Answer (score 3):

As an addition to @EpicPandaForce:

Observable#just is eager, Observable#fromCallable is lazy.

Example eager:
Observable.just(methodCall()) -> first methodCall will be evaluted during assembly-time. methodCall()-Value will be captured and used as input-parameter for Observable#just. This value will be stored in the observable. Everything to this point has already happend without any subscription. When subscribing to created Observable the captured value will be replayed on each subscription.

Example lazy:
Observable.fromCallable(() -> methodCall()) -> during assembly-time the observable will be created with a reference to the lambda. methodCall() will not be invoked during assembly-time. The lambda execution will happen on every subscription.

If you want to defer expensive work until the first subscription happens you would use Observable#defer / Observable#fromCallable. When dealing with sync. values, which are already present or are very expensive to created, you would use Observable#just.

Also please have a look at https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#assembly-time (Assembly time/ Subscription time/ Runtime)